# Blaring noise from newish indoor AC unit

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Why is my AC making a noise like Mass Effect Reaper every 20-60 seconds and how can I stop this?

https://webmshare.com/play/qd07r

Comment: Mass Effect Reaper. NO idea what that is. "Welcome my son, welcome to the machine".

Comment: Sorry I was being dumb but you can hear it in the video.

Comment: Sometimes wall A/C units have a mechanism that rotates the vent louvers. Kinda sounds like plastic gears grinding, then again it kinda sounds like and electrical switch firing rapidly. Is this new behavior, was it not making a noise previously ?